# How to associate opencv image with dimensions in mm?

Tags: opencv

I have an image of 2061x2533 which represent an area of 429x349mm. When I open this saved image in Adobe Illustrator I would like the size to be exactly 429x349mm.

So I have a `dpi` value associated to my opencv image, but when I use `cv.imwrite` I did not find a way to set the `dpi` parameter to be considered by Photoshop or Illustrator.

Any idea?

Comment: Any particular file format? Any particular language? The only [flags](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga292d81be8d76901bff7988d18d2b42ac) remotely related to resolution are only for TIFF. I'd look for a library that's focused on image I/O (the functions in OpenCV are more of a convenience, with only basic features), or working with image metadata.

Comment: My output image is in JPG

Comment: opencv is for computer vision, not for image editing. You could try to find different image writing libraries with features that you need, and write your opencv results with those libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Micka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393191/micka) said in his comment, opencv is for computer vision not for image editing. So you need another library to handle this.

You could for instance use [pillow](/questions/tagged/pillow):

```
from PIL import Image
dpi = 150

cim = cv.imread(str(filename))

...

im = Image.fromarray(cim)
im.save('foobar.jpg', dpi=(dpi, dpi))
```